# Objective-C: basic memory management. Ownership of object?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am looking through the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) of Apple.

For the following code:

```
-(NSString *)fullName {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                                                  self.firstName,
                                                  self.lastName];
    return string;
}
```

> Following the basic rules, you don’t own the string returned by stringWithFormat:, so you can safely return the string from the method.

...Therefore, do not have to release it.

Basic rule from another part of the guide:

> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”

...This makes you the owner)

So, who owns the string?

Answer (score 2):

At this point, the autorelease pool owns the string. It was originally created by the Foundation framework, which allocated the object and thereby became its owner. Foundation then switched its ownership over to the autorelease pool by calling `autorelease` before returning the object to your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use stringWithFormat:, the caller does not have ownership of the object. Therefore, you can return the object without calling autorelease. If you had used initWithFormat:, you would need to autorelease the object before returning.

Answer (score 0):

"Owns" is a poor term -- appropriate in some circumstances, but not generally.  The real questions are:

1) Are you assured that the object will be `retain`ed until you no longer need to access it?

2) Are you responsible for `release`ing it when it's no longer needed?  (This latter attribute can be considered to be "ownership".)

In the above example the object is `retain`ed and will be `autorelease`d when the application "comes up for air".  So you are not responsible for releasing it, and it will be `retain`ed for the duration of the invocation of your method (and beyond), without any more effort on your part.

Comment: +1 Agree that the whole 'ownership' concept doesn't quite fit, but it's hard to avoid as Apple added it to the docs at some point.

Answer (score 0):

**You own objects that you create (using alloc/copy) or retain.**
As a thumb rule, objects returned by factory methods are most likely to be autoreleased objects and no need to release them.
this explains why you should not release NSString obtained from `stringWithFormat` method.
following change would make string own the returned object in your first case.

```
string = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.firstName,self.lastName] retain];
```

With alloc/copy you create objects that needs to be released explicitly - this explains your second case.